# Image in the middle of a blank page

Tags: html

I'm creating a blank page with a image in the middle of the page. 
I'm aligning the image in html, but it doesn't work. I can only align it left and right and if I am setting aling="middle" it doesn't do anything...

So... what can i do?

Comment: Can you show some more code. It sounds like you are just looking for `text-align: center` on `body`

Comment: Try: `<img style="vertical-align:middle;" align="center" href="Images\myImage.jpg">`

Comment: This doesn't works.... I just want the image in the middle of a blank page.

Answer (score 3):

From: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

```
<head>
    <style>
       img {
           position: absolute;
           top: 50%;
           left: 50%;
           width: 500px;
           height: 500px;
           margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
           margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
       }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: that works, but i want the image in the middle of the whole page, not in the middle of the bottom

Comment: Note that this code causes *any* image to be centered. If you want to target just one, then give it an id like "centerimage" and change `img` in the above to `#centerimage`.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend the method suggested by Whistletoe

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/149/2/9/fluffy_confused_kitten_gif_3_by_wonderfuday-d51jxyi.gif" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   margin-top: -150px;
   margin-left: -200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NgpTw/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp

> The align attribute specifies the alignment of an image according to
>   the surrounding element.
>
> The  element is an inline element (it does not insert a new line
>   on a page), meaning that text and other elements can wrap around it.
>   Therefore, it can be useful to specify the alignment of the image
>   according to surrounding elements.

So all works as should work. If you want to place image at center of page, you must wrap "img" tag with any text tag (like "p" or "div"), and set "align" attribute to that tag, not to "img" tag.

Comment: Or change to `display: block`